# ListView Height Fill Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout which looks somewhat like this

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include android:id="@+id/tb_cntnr" layout="@layout/app_toolbar"/>

<TextView
    style="@style/item_label"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tb_cntnr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/maint_label"
    android:text="@string/label_title"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/actions"
    android:layout_below="@+id/maint_label"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="false"
    tools:listitem="@layout/action_list_item"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        style="@style/item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_notes"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/notestext"
        style="@style/item_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/label_notes"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want 
1. toolbar set at top of screen (it is)
2. action title textview align top (it is)
3. notes section (id-noteslayout) align bottom of screen
4. list fills up the remaining area between (2) and (3)

I am kind of clueless what to do

Comment: So what is happening right now? Can you post a screenshot or describe it more

Comment: currently, the list is stretched full and overlaps the linearlayout (id-noteslayout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have put listview height as fill parent, it is occupying the entire screen. If you want it to be between title and notes layout , add two conditions to your listview - below title , above notes view : android:layout_below="@id/maint_label" , android:layout_above="@id/notes_layout"

Comment: I ended up adding  android:layout_below="@+id/maint_label"  android:layout_above="@+id/noteslayout" to the listview. dont know if there's a better way to do it

Comment: Also, "+" is only used while creating the id. There is no need to use plus while referencing the id. Like , you can remove the "+" here while referencing in the list view  android:layout_below="@id/maint_label"

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a very similar thing to what you did with alignBottom. Here, you have to use `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/id_of_linear_layout` so that it won't overlap what's below it. You will need to set the id of the linear layout and replace the above code with the new id.